# How can I shorten my regex for matching "XXd XXh XXm" strings that contain only two of the parts?

Tags: regex, parsley.js

I've got an HTML text input with a Parsley JS pattern validation where I'm hoping to validate a day hour minute string in the pattern of 99d 99m 99h.  I've got the regex working for the entire string (all three segments present (d m h)) but I'd like it to also validate if only one or two of the three segments are present (00d 00h or 00h 00m or 00h or 00m or 00d).

Here's my pattern:

```
(?:(\d+d)\s)?(?:(\d+h)\s)?(?:(\d+m))
```

Is there a way to group these so the other five patterns also match without writing several more pattern groups?

```
(?:(\d+d)\s)?(?:(\d+h)\s)?(?:(\d+m))?:(?:(\d+d)\s)?(?:(\d+h)\s))?:(?:(\d+h)\s)?(?:(\d+m)?(\d+d)\s)?(\d+h)\s)?(\d+m)\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be 100% on what your needs are, but couldn't you do some version of what I have below here, adding in some whitespace patterns or something?

```
^(\d{2}[dhm]){1,3}$
```

*Edit based on comments*
What about this version?

```
^(\d{2}d\s\d{2}h\s\d{2}m)|(\d{2}[dh]\s\d{2}m)|(\d{2}d\s\d{2}[hm])|(\d{2}[dhm])$‌​
```

Comment: I'd like it to require a single space between the 1d 1h 1m segments.  When I try the regex below, it requires a trailing space after the input to match which is not quite what I'd like to happen: `^(\d{1}[dhm]\s){1,3}$`

Comment: What about: ^((\d{2}[dh]\s){0,2}(\d{2}m)?){1,3}\s*$

Comment: Matches if all three values are present (0d 0h 0m) but I may have cases where only 0d or 0h or 0m are present without the other two values.  Not sure how to make a regex group optional.

Comment: They are all optional. I tested it. It only requires one to match.

Comment: When I test with 11d or 11d 11h, it only matches if I add a space after the last segment since the \s is part of the group.  If I make the \s in the first grouping for d or h look like \s{0,1} then it matches 11d11h11m with no spaces in-between.

Comment: Hmm.  This was the best I could come up with meeting all that criteria.  

`^(\d{2}d\s\d{2}h\s\d{2}m)|(\d{2}[dh]\s\d{2}m)|(\d{2}d\s\d{2}[hm])|(\d{2}[dhm])$`

Comment: This regex works except it requires a space after the letter if only one or two segments (1d 1h or 1h 1m) are present.  `^((\d{2}[dh]\s){0,2}(\d{2}m)?){1,3}\s*$`